# Image Scaling on btn click

Tags: html, css, angularjs, amazon-web-services

Say for example, I have a div with a dynamic image which is stored in amazon web server, and i have such div multiple times in my website. What  want to do is to click the image to enlarge the image. How should i proceed?

I have created a model which works when pressed on the image but the images are not dynamic.

I have the image link in amazon server

Expected: Something like in some websites image enlarges on click. And the images should be dynamic. Not static image

Comment: please add a `codesandbox` link with the working code. thaks

Comment: Once there was a plugin/library called Lightbox. I wonder, if it is still around, but that should do the trick.

Comment: Ya I know about Lightbox. Lightbox must work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once there was a plugin/library called Lightbox. I wonder, if it is still around, but that should do the trick.